# Problem using the acro-package and \today

Tags: datetime, acro, datetime2

I have a problem using the `tooltip` option of the `acro`-package and the command `\today`.

In my document i load `\usepackage[tooltip = true]{acro}`, where the option `tooltip=true` loads the package `pdfcomment` which loads the package `datetime`.

The package `datetime` changes the behaviour of the command `\today` (it prints now with the DayOfWeek). I used `datetime2` in my document since it is the newer version of `datetime`.
The problem is: datetime2 and it's formating options are totally ignored! It does not matter if i load it before or after the `acro` package.

I want: `15th June, 2016`

I get: `Wednesday 15th June, 2016`

Because of the problems above I tried `\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}` instead of `datetime2`. But the package option `nodayofweek` creats another error with the package `\usepackage{catoptions}`:

```
 LaTeX Error: Option clash for package datetime.
```

I use `catoptions` to define a command `\Autoref*` (which does the same as `\autoref*` but with a big beginning letter instead of a small letter (e.g. 'Section' instead of 'section').

I have no idea what i should do since so many packages are involved ...

Minimalexample

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% \usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage[tooltip=true]{acro}
\usepackage{catoptions}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: this is not really a problem with `acro`, right? The MWE will produce the same problem if you replace `\usepackage[tooltip=true]{acro}`with `\usepackage{pdfcomment}`, won't it, or even if you leave it away completely and just load `datetime` with options and `catoptions`?

Comment: very strange ... With just `\usepackage{pdfcomment}` instead of `\usepackage[tooltip=true]{acro}` the error message with `catoptions`disappears! So it is an error produced from the combinaton of this three packages and packageoptions!

Comment: `acro` loads `pdfcomment` just before begin document and indeed if I place it there and remove `acro` I can reproduce the issue. Explicitly loading `pdfcomment` earlier seems to avoid the problem.

Comment: Loading `pdfcomment` before `catoptions` seems to 'solve' the problem. The error disappears and I can load `datetime` with the `[nodayofweek]` option. I do not understand why but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\PassOptionsToPackage` to indicate options for packages that are loaded internally by other packages. For example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\PassOptionsToPackage{nodayofweek}{datetime}
\usepackage[tooltip=true]{acro}
\usepackage{catoptions}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

If you want to use `datetime2`, you'll need to ensure that `\today` is set to `\DTMtoday` at the beginning of the document to prevent other packages overriding it:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[tooltip=true]{acro}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\today\DTMtoday}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

Edit: `\DTMtoday` requires at least v1.4 of `datetime2`.